# Stepwise observation deletion in regression

Tags: r, regression, machine-learning, robust

My data have 500 observations. The response variable includes toxic level and it has several predictor variables. I realized that all observations produced a noise, but higher intensity of toxic level data (above the 2nd quertile) showed a significant relationship with predictors. Is there any way to carryout regression that progressively delelet obervation (e.g., increasing toxic level) until the model get improved? Please provide me R package and method, if possible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Removal of data is not good statistical practice unless you have compelling documentation that the data were erroneous. Instead choose a model that assumes less about distributions and shapes of predictor effects (e..g, proportional odds ordinal logistic model for continuous $Y$, regression splines for $X$).

Comment: Thank you, can you please provide me a link of detail description of this method and R package? @frank-harrell

Comment: http://biostat.mc.vanderbilt.edu/rms. See course notes link.

Comment: Such a resourceful website. Greatly appreciated !